# fix image being shrank in bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-vue

I'm trying to keep the logo images filling their "circle containers" and prevent them from shrinking with the width of the browser.

The containers are made 100px by 100px with:

```
.timeline-image::before {
    content: "";
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background-color: #fff;
    z-index: 1;
```

The images inside should have 90px:

```
.timeline-image img {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 100;
    width: 90px;
    height: auto;
}
```

however, under 1127px in viewport width the image will start to shrink in width.

How should I approach this?

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/github/AngelinCalu/bs-vue-timeline-demo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this piece of code

```
<div class="timeline-image text-sm-center mx-md-4 col-md-1 offset-md-0 col-1 offset-1 order-1">
   <img src="img/microsoft.png" alt="Microsoft Corporation" class="img-fluid">
</div>
```

for this

```
<div class="timeline-image d-flex justify-content-center mx-md-4 col-md-1 offset-md-0 col-1 offset-1 order-1">
  <img src="img/microsoft.png" alt="Microsoft Corporation">
</div>
```

I removed the `img-fluid` class, it caused the logo to be reduced. I also removed the `text-sm-center` class because there is no text only for the image, but I added two`d-flex justify-content-center` centered in the flex object.

Comment: Have you tested this? It seems to make the image height go nuts.

Comment: I tested and it works as it should -> [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/bs-vue-timeline-demo-gsjql) I added to style to App.vue

Comment: it did work, but only after I added `object-fit: contain;` to `.timeline-image img`